# Resolve $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\tan 3x}{\tan 5x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I started resolving this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan 3x}{\tan 5x}$$

so:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan 3x}{ \tan 5x} & = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x }}{\frac{\sin 5x}{\cos 5x}} \\ \\ & = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{ \sin (3x) \cdot \cos (5x)}{ \sin(5x) \cdot \cos (3x)}\\ \\ & = \quad?\end{align}$$

Could someone help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\tan3x}{\tan5x}=\frac35\cdot\frac{\sin3x}{3x}\cdot\frac1{\dfrac{\sin5x}{5x}}\cdot\frac1{\cos3x}\cdot \cos5x$$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=\quad?$$ and $$\lim_{k\to 0}\cos k=\quad?$$

Comment: @amWhy, This hint makes sense for me. What is it so wrong?

Comment: It is fine. My apologies for overlooking the obvious cancellation! Sorry for the distraction. (You too, @MichaelT: apologies.)